# The jdbcSyncConnector cannot track the schema to insert or update the message from kafka topic

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, debezium

I am using two containers one is the postgres:latest image and the other is debezium/connect:latest. There is a topic that its data needs to be inserted into a specific schema in the database. Here is the configuration of the connector:

```
{
  "name": "connector_consumer_controllers",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "jbx.t11.controller",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://10.5.0.13:5432/test-db?currentSchema=t11",
    "connection.username": "JOULEBOX_DATABASE_USER",
    "connection.password": "root",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "slot.name": "t11_slot_controller",
    "table.name.format": "controller", 
    "primary.key.mode": "record_key",
    "primary.key.fields": "controller_id",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "schema.evolve":"true"
  }
}
```

I also tried searchpath=t11, search_path=t11. I tried running "ALTER ROLE "USER" SET search_path TO t11;" But none of them are working and it keeps updating the table in the public schema. I know that the latest version of debezium/connect has all the required jdbc class, so no need to add any thing to it, but it seems there must be another command to include the schema name in the connectionURL. I would be gratefull if someone could help. Thanks

I expected that the connector update the table in the specified schema